# Get position of tile in tileset

Tags: grid

How can I get the position of tile 14 (or any other) when only knowing the following:
Tile ID: 14
Rows: 4
Columns: 7

The end result should be 2x4.

Comment: Do consider waiting a while before accepting an answer, as there might appear a more correct and elaborated one. I'm not bitter, but I'm disappointed.

Comment: Actually yes, Lars' answer was better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Column = TileID mod Rows
Row = TileID div Rows
```

so in most programming languages your example would be:

```
col = 14 % 4;
row = 14 / 4;
```

Answer (score 9):

Such a bijective mapping is much easier to express if your tile indices and rows/columns are zero-based.

```
col: 0  1  2  3
  [  0  1  2  3  // row 0
     4  5  6  7  // row 1
     8  9 10 11  // row 2
    12 13 14 15  // row 3
    ...
```

If you look at the column numbers, as the column number increases by one, so does the tile index. More particularly, there's a pattern that for each row, it starts on a multiple of the row width, and increases by one.

This means that if we could get rid of that term, we would have our column number.

The modulus operator (commonly % in most languages) will take a number in a range [0,n) and map it to the values 0 through n-1, *wrapping* around.

That is, `7 % 4 == 3`, `8 % 4 == 0`, and so on.

A suitable expression for the column index is thus `col = idx % width`.

For the row, we need an expression that results in the same value for all values in the row. An operation related to modulus is division, so it's likely useful.

`8/4 = 2, 9/4 = 2.25, 10/4 = 2.50, 11/4 = 2.75`, which is almost what we want. We can feed the result of that into the `floor()` operation, which truncates away the fractional part of a floating point result, or in the case of integer division, it's already done for you.

So in summary:

```
zero_based_col =       zero_based_idx % row_width
zero_based_row = floor(zero_based_idx / row_width)
```

Comment: Ahh right you are, didn't see it wasn't zero based :)